# Is it possible to make SVM probabiility predictions without tm and RTextTools using e1071 in R?

Tags: r, nlp, tm

I am trying to create a topic classifier from an employee satisfaction survey. The survey contains several commentary fields, and therefore want to produce an effective way of classifying what a single comment is about, and later also whether it is positive or negative (pretty standard sentiment analysis).
I already have a sample data from last years survey, where comments have been given a category manually.

The data is structured in a CSV file with three rows:

The document (or comment) - The topic - The sentiment

One example could be:

Document: I am afraid of violence from our customers, since my position does not have sufficient sercurity

Topic: Violence

Sentiment: Negative

*(Very crude example, but bear with me)*

My tool for making this classifier is RStudio, but I only have access to a limited number of packages. I do not have access to tm or RTextTools, which are the packages I usually use when I am doing projects outside of work. I pretty much only have access to e1071, and that is why I figured a support vector machine might do the trick. I have bad experiences with NaiveBayes when dealing with text analytics, but I am of course open to any advice. Is it possible at all to do text mining without tm or RTextTools? I have access to the NLP and tau packages

Comment: You should provide a code showing what you have tried so far and some reproducible data

Comment: So far I've tried emulating this:
http://www.ida.liu.se/~jodfo01/files/r-svm-pres.pdf
Not succesfully though. But please don't miss the point. This is not about providing me with a code fix that I can just paste in. This is all about discussing whether or not it is possible to do text mining at all without these packages. And maybe some ideas as to how one might go about it.

Answer (score 0):

from the help page of `predict.svm`

```
# S3 method for svm
predict(object, newdata, decision.values = FALSE,
probability = FALSE, ..., na.action = na.omit)
```

you could use the option **probability** by setting it to`TRUE`.
ie. `predict(foo,bar, probability = TRUE)`